# Sparkle in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5, sparkle

I have an issue adding the sparkle framework in Xcode 5. It is essentially described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348239/sparkle-10-9-linking-error). The problem is that sparkle is not copied to the frameworks folder. The solution is to download the source code, change some settings and build it yourself. But: During building I get an error:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:SULocalizedString(@"Update Error!", nil) defaultButton:SULocalizedString(@"Cancel Update", nil) alternateButton:nil otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:[error localizedDescription]];
```

produces

> Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)

and I can't figure out how to fix this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem today. The change is pretty simple.

Change:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:SULocalizedString(@"Update Error!", nil)
                                 defaultButton:SULocalizedString(@"Cancel Update", nil)
                               alternateButton:nil
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:[error localizedDescription]];
```

To:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:SULocalizedString(@"Update Error!", nil)
                                 defaultButton:SULocalizedString(@"Cancel Update", nil)
                               alternateButton:nil
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:@"%@", [error localizedDescription]];
```

The explanation, in case you are interested, is that the `informativeTextWithFormat` is actually the start of a variable argument list, of which the first parameter is the format string, and the subsequent ones are the inputs to that format. The error is because the format is from a runtime string (rather than a compile time constant string), and therefore it is not possible to validate it at compile time - a malicious user could (somehow) alter the format string, at runtime, to execute malicious code from within this app.

It is the same as the difference between:

```
NSLog([error localizatedDescription]);
```

And:

```
NSLog( @"%@", [error localizatedDescription]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This issue is now fixed in Sparkle.