# How to use sparkle updater in swift app?

Tags: cocoa, swift, updates, sparkle

Does anyone know how I would go about setting this up in my Swift App? I have tried setting it up with the cocoa instructions, but I have problems with my app finding the framework. It seems that Swift doesn't have framework folders anymore.

What steps should I take to get this up and running? It's just a .app without an installer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As has been answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19357321/4396258

You need to change the destination to "Frameworks" rather than resources in your copy phase